# What does bound values between 0.0 and 1.0 mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

From [the documentation for AVMetadataObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) I read:

> For video content, the bounding rectangle may be expressed using
>   scalar values in the range 0.0 to 1.0. Scalar values remain meaningful
>   even when the original video has been scaled down.

What does that mean?

Comment: {0, 0} top-left {1, 1} bottom-right corner?

Comment: But how can I use these values for setting frame for a UIView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you a basic example. Let's say we have two views A and B

1. A = {0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0}
2. B = {100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0}

So now we can translate in to our new coordinate system where

1. A = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0}

Let's do some basic calculation for b

```
the point x : 320 == 1 like 100 == x so 100 / 320 = x = 0.3125
the point y : 568 == 1 like 100 == y so 100 / 568 = y = 0.1760
```

Do the same calculation for width and height and you will have your new frame translated into the new coordinate system, and obviously you can do the opposite calculation to translate back to your system of coordinates.